# What is a "Chain of Chinese whispers"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I had never (before today) heard this phrase. I attempted to Google it, but only found [examples of its use](https://www.google.com/search?q="chain+of+chinese+whispers"), not much different from [my first experience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9960948/418413). (I also tried two idiom dictionaries, but *chain of Chinese whispers* did not even present there.)

What does it mean and where should I have looked to find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Chinese whispers* is another name for the [game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers) also known as telephone, grapevine, or whisper down the lane. In this game, each person whispers a phrase to the next person in line. The phrase is usually unrecognizable by the time it reaches the end of the line.

"A chain of Chinese whispers" appears to be used for the analogous real-life process where a rumour gets totally distorted while being passed along.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that this language is not an idiom but instead, say, a metaphor?

Comment: Good point. It's certainly closer to a metaphor than an idiom.