# Word for change of information during transmission

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

> A: John's eyes are black.
>
> B: John's pupils are black.
>
> C: John's students are black.

When information gets passed from one person to another, its meaning may be altered. Is there a word for this situation? It might be used in the following sentence:

> Misunderstanding arose because of `......`.

Phrases and non-nouns are also welcome.

Comment: It will be quickest to direct you to <http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62855/what-is-a-chain-of-chinese-whispers>  There is only one answer but some of the suggestions may be useful.

Comment: Minor nitpick: all pupils are black. It is irises which have different colors.

Comment: I would call the changes "transcription errors".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no disagreement between

> A: John's eyes are black.
>   B: John's pupils are black.

Neither is there any contradiction between

> C: John's students are black
>   B: John's pupils are black.

But in the sequence, A: B: C: the phrase

> B: John's pupils are black.

changes its meaning, an example of total lexical ambiguity, in this case created by two words,
**1** the **homonym** "*pupils*," schoolchildren (from *puer* +diminutive suffix) and "*pupils*"   the centre of the eyes by metonymy fom the previous meaning here used for *eyes* by synecdoche,
**2**, the **polysemous** word "black".

*The Cause of the Ambiguity* is **recategorisation**  or **recontextualisation** of phrase B:. The listener has made **a category error**.

This *Process of Misunderstanding* comes under the heading of **pragmatics.**

The *Circumstance* leading to the misunderstanding is **universal lexical ambiguity.**

Answer (score 13):

[Whenever information is moving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction) between a sender and a receiver, any change in the message is considered a

> transmission error

Answer (score 13):

I'd refer to this as a "game of telephone," after the children's game where you gather around in a circle and whisper a message to the person next to you until you get to the end and compare the initial and final messages (which of course end up rather different with enough people).

This game is also sometimes called "Chinese whispers" by British speakers, but that name might be offensive to some people.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers) has more information about the game if you aren't familiar with it.

Comment: +1 for what I expect to be the most widely understood answer. This is definitely the most common name for the phenomenon that I'm familiar with.

Comment: I, too, upvoted this answer, although I'd probably opt use the slightly shorter phrase "telephone game," i.e.: _A misunderstanding arose because of a telephone game._

Answer (score 9):

"... because of ***garbling***."  Or "... because the transmission was ***garbled***."

> [**garble**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/garble) -
>
> - to so alter or distort as to create a wrong impression or change the meaning
> - to introduce textual error into (a message) by inaccurate encipherment, transmission, or decipherment

Answer (score 4):

If you permit replacing *information* with *data*, then not limited to transmission, but generally it is **data corruption**. Per Wikipedia:

> [Data corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_corruption) refers to errors in computer data that occur during writing, reading, storage, **transmission**, our processing, which introduce unintended changes to the original data.

You might also consider using the opposite term: **information/data integrity loss**.

Answer (score 3):

For information it would be **distortion**, as defined [here](http://www.igi-global.com/dictionary/information-distortion/41806):

> The tendency of information communicated within and between individuals and organizations to be altered, omitted, or re-organized as it is communicated.

For distortions in human communication you might also describe the situation figuratively by likening it to the children's game [Chinese whispers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers).

Comment: @Rathony But are there any guidelines that "we need to check" answers in low quality queue "if the answer is a duplicate?" Duplicate answers shall be closed (for example according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). It's not that "looks OK" prevents closing, these are two different queues.

Answer (score 3):

Consider, ***grapevine** source*

> grapevine: the informal transmission of information, gossip, or rumor from person to person
>
> hear something on/through the grapevine: to hear news from someone who heard that news from someone else [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grapevine)

Answer (score 3):

In the case of mistaking *pupil*, the anatomical feature, for *pupil*, meaning student, the problem is perhaps more one of **misunderstanding** than communication. So I might say

> Confusion arose because of a misunderstanding.

*Transmission error*, *distortion*, and *data corruption* are fine for telecommunications equipment but not for communication between people. (Between people, *distortion* indicates an intent to deceive or slant information.)

Another possibility is **a miscommunication** as in

> Misunderstanding arose because of a miscommunication.